# What WordPress API function lists active/inactive plugins?

Tags: plugins, api

After seeing thousands of useful API functions in the WordPress core, I'm surprised to discover today that there ain't a function that would list the active plug-ins. I don't know you but I'm quite surprised at that.

I was wondering if there is a reason for missing that? 
If so, I'd like to know about it.

And, if there is a quick PHP snippet you know of that could give you a list of active plugins, ( the same way that a `get_post_types('','names');` does for CPT's or `get_taxonomies('','names');` does for CTs ), I'd appreciate it if you provide the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins/)

[`get_plugins()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugins)

and `get_option('active_plugins')`

Comment: Interesting. So we do have such a function. That's good. But check this (https://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=wordpress+get+active+&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wordpress+get+active+plugins ) or this (https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=wordpress+list+plugins+&oq=wordpress+list+plugins+&aq=f&aqi=g-K1g-b3&aql=&gs_l=hp.3..0i30j0i8l3.55111.55111.2.55405.1.1.0.0.0.0.144.144.0j1.1.0...0.0.sl9KTuxugVc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=dd7cf850984208aa&biw=1125&bih=1323) to see how google fails to pick that up.

Answer (score 8):

### There multiple WordPress Apis for getting a list of plugins like OTP listed in his answer.

#### [`get_plugins()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_plugins/) :Check the plugins directory and retrieve all plugin files with plugin data. Returns an array.  **Note:** Only works on the admin side

Example:

```
function list_the_plugins() {
    $plugins = get_plugins();
        foreach ( $plugins as $plugin ) {
        var_dump( $plugin );
    }
```

Returns:

```
array
  'Name' => string 'WP Coda Slider' (length=14)
  'PluginURI' => string 'http://c3mdigital.com/wp-coda-slider/' (length=37)
  'Version' => string '0.3.2' (length=5)
  'Description' => string 'Add a jQuery Coda slider to any WordPress post or page' (length=54)
  'Author' => string 'c3mdigital' (length=10)
  'AuthorURI' => string 'http://c3mdigital.com/' (length=22)
  'TextDomain' => string '' (length=0)
  'DomainPath' => string '' (length=0)
  'Network' => boolean false
  'Title' => string 'WP Coda Slider' (length=14)
  'AuthorName' => string 'c3mdigital' (length=10)
```

`get_option( 'active_plugins' )` Returns the path relative to wp-content/plugins of the plugin file:

Example:

```
function list_the_plugins() {
    $plugins = get_option ( 'active_plugins', array () );
    foreach ( $plugins as $plugin ) {
        echo "<li>$plugin</li>";
    }
}
```

Returns:

- debug-bar-extender/debug-bar-extender.php
- debug-bar/debug-bar.php
- log-deprecated-notices/log-deprecated-notices.php
- manage-post-schedule/manage-post-schedule.php
- wp-coda-slider/wpcodaslider.php

#### Other API functions related to plugin status:

- [`is_plugin_active()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_plugin_active/) Checks if plugin is active
- [`is_plugin_inactive()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_plugin_inactive/) Checks if plugin is inactive
- [`is_plugin_active_for_network()`](http://queryposts.com/function/is_plugin_active_for_network/) Checks if plugin is network activated
- [`validate_active_plugins()`](http://queryposts.com/function/validate_active_plugins/) Checks all active plugins and deactivates invalid ones
- [`get_dropins()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_dropins/) Gets plugins in wp-content folder
- [`get_mu_plugins()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_mu_plugins/) Gets Must use plugins

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to get 2 seperate lists, active and inactive plugins. This is what i came up with:

```
$plugins = get_plugins();
$activated_plugins = array();
$deactivated_plugins = array();
foreach($plugins as $key => $val){
    if(is_plugin_inactive($key)){
        array_push($deactivated_plugins, $key);
    } else {
        array_push($activated_plugins, $key);
    }
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($deactivated_plugins); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($activated_plugins); echo '</pre>';
```

Will print 2 seperate arrays of active and inactive plugins.