# List out all the plugins on Wordpress instance

Tags: plugins

As an example, my site is `mysite.com`

I want `mysite.com/wordpress_plugins` to return the output of `get_plugins()` from https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugins

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The get_plugins() function will return an array of plugin. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugins . You can use that array of information to extract the info you want.

You could use that function in a shortcode, then put the shortcode on your page.

I note that there are plugins that purport to list plugins. In fact, some of those plugins will allow you to use a shortcode to list them.

So, it depends on whether you want to 'roll your own' or use a plugin. The information is out there (do a plugin search for 'list plugins').

You might also look at the answer to this question: [What WordPress API function lists active/inactive plugins?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52144/what-wordpress-api-function-lists-active-inactive-plugins)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to display a list of all of your plugins on your page, you could use a WordPress shortcode on your page as Rick above has suggested.

Some example code to show how to do this is below:

```
function list_my_plugins(){
    $plugins = get_plugins();
    $output = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $plugins as $plugin ){
        $output .= '<li>' . $plugin['Name'] . '</li>';
    }
    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('list-my-plugins', 'list_my_plugins');
```

Simply add the above code to your functions.php file or create it as a plugin, then you'd just need to use the shortcode `[list-my-plugins]` on your page.

You can see a full list of the plugin information that is available in the returned array on the codex page in the 'Example output': https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugins